# ASP.NET Forms Authentication is returning blank identity.name on subsequent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I am inheriting this project, so there's a lot going on that I'm not sure about. We're making a copy to create a new site using the same feature set (same client). This works as-is on their current site so I'm not sure what I'm missing. It's an ecommerce website where the checkout process is handled on another server (checkout.domain.com, for example) and so it passes a GUID value as a URL parameter so it looks like this: `http://checkout.domain.com/Checkout.aspx?u=f1a1b32d-38ae-4f5c-810e-4b9b8c1be448`

`Checkout.aspx` then determines if it's an anonymous user or a signed in user, logs them in (or sets the Identity principal) and redirects. This works, except that after the redirect `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is empty.

Here's what's happening:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(r["IsAnonymous"]))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new MyIdentity(r["Login"].ToString()), new string[0]);
    Utility.AnonymousUser = true; // At this point User is set and the Identity.Name value is still present
}
else
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session["CurrUser"] = null;
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(r["Login"].ToString(), false);
    Utility.AnonymousUser = false;
}
string redirectUrl = string.Empty;
```

Here's the `MyIdentity` class for reference:

```
[Serializable, ComVisible(true)]
public class MyIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get { return "Cookie"; } }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get { return false; } }

    public string Name { get { return m_name; } }

    public MyIdentity(string name) { m_name = name; }

    private string m_name;
}
```

However, once it redirects to the page that handles checkout `Identity.Name` is empty again.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I should note that this issue only seems to crop up with the `IsAnonymous` section above. Actual authenticated users seem to be fine.

Comment: Since you copied the code, did you also copy the server settings?

Comment: It is residing on the same server so the settings should theoretically be identical. And the only differences I can tell with the web.config are domain name changes and connection strings.

Comment: @JoshStevens It is recreating the AuthCookie based on the GUID value on the new domain.

Comment: It is a subdomain. And a majority of the cookies are having the domain set to `.domain.com`